# Getting type error TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
def escape_characters(message):
    for escape in ESCAPE_TTS_CHARACTERS:
        message = message.replace(escape, "\\"+escape)
    for escape in ESCAPE_EDI_CHARACTERS:
        message = message.replace(escape, "\\"+escape)
    for hexa in HEXA_TTS_CHARACTERS:
        message = message.replace(hexa, "\\x"+ format(ord(hexa), "x"))
    for hexa in HEXA_EDI_CHARACTERS:
        message = message.replace(hexa, "\\x"+ format(ord(hexa), "x"))
    message = message.replace("\x00", "\\x00")
    return message
ESCAPE_TTS_CHARACTERS = ["\\", "{", "}"]
HEXA_TTS_CHARACTERS = ["$", "%"]
ESCAPE_EDI_CHARACTERS = ["'", "*"]
HEXA_EDI_CHARACTERS = ["&", "+", "#", "\"", ":"]    

blob=b'\n\x11\n\x06TmgTty\x10\x00\x1a\x05\n\x03SIM\n\x16\n\x05Event\x10\x00\x1a\x0b\n\tDeparture\n\x12\n\x04Unit\x10\x00\x1a\x08\n\x06Minute\n\x11\n\x05Value\x10\x00\x1a\x06\n\x04-976\n\r\n\x07RefCity\x10\x00\x1a\x00\n\n\n\x04Date\x10\x00\x1a\x00\n\n\n\x04Time\x10\x00\x1a\x00\n\x0c\n\x06DftRul\x10\x00\x1a\x00\n\x0e\n\x05TiaId\x10\x00\x1a\x03\n\x011\n\x10\n\x07LastUid\x10\x00\x1a\x03\n\x011\n\x0b\n\x05Cabin\x10\x00\x1a\x00\n\x0e\n\x08BkgClass\x10\x00\x1a\x00\n\x0c\n\x06TgType\x10\x00\x1a\x00\n\r\n\x07TgValue\x10\x00\x1a\x00'

print(escape_characters(blob))
```

## Getting below error

message = message.replace(escape, "\"+escape)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

**This code is working fine in Python 2 but getting above error in python 3**

Comment: In Python 2 str and bytes were the same type. In Python 3 they're different and you can't mix them.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Mark, can you please suggest how to implement this function in Python3.

Comment: Well, do you want to operate on bytes or on strings?

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the `replace` method expects bytes for the first parameter, not a string which you have passed. Syntactically you can specify a bytes literal by prefixing a bytes string with `b`.

`message = message.replace(b'0', "\\x00")`

Comment: Both arguments need to be `bytes` objects.

Answer (score 0):

This solves your error, your are defining your string as bytes-like with the b attribute in `blob= b'...'` , but the replace function with string arguments only accepts strings.

```
def escape_characters(message):
    for escape in ESCAPE_TTS_CHARACTERS:
        message = message.replace(escape, "\\"+escape)
    for escape in ESCAPE_EDI_CHARACTERS:
        message = message.replace(escape, "\\"+escape)
    for hexa in HEXA_TTS_CHARACTERS:
        message = message.replace(hexa, "\\x"+ format(ord(hexa), "x"))
    for hexa in HEXA_EDI_CHARACTERS:
        message = message.replace(hexa, "\\x"+ format(ord(hexa), "x"))
    message = message.replace("\x00", "\\x00")
    return message
ESCAPE_TTS_CHARACTERS = ["\\", "{", "}"]
HEXA_TTS_CHARACTERS = ["$", "%"]
ESCAPE_EDI_CHARACTERS = ["'", "*"]
HEXA_EDI_CHARACTERS = ["&", "+", "#", "\"", ":"]    

blob='\n\x11\n\x06TmgTty\x10\x00\x1a\x05\n\x03SIM\n\x16\n\x05Event\x10\x00\x1a\x0b\n\tDeparture\n\x12\n\x04Unit\x10\x00\x1a\x08\n\x06Minute\n\x11\n\x05Value\x10\x00\x1a\x06\n\x04-976\n\r\n\x07RefCity\x10\x00\x1a\x00\n\n\n\x04Date\x10\x00\x1a\x00\n\n\n\x04Time\x10\x00\x1a\x00\n\x0c\n\x06DftRul\x10\x00\x1a\x00\n\x0e\n\x05TiaId\x10\x00\x1a\x03\n\x011\n\x10\n\x07LastUid\x10\x00\x1a\x03\n\x011\n\x0b\n\x05Cabin\x10\x00\x1a\x00\n\x0e\n\x08BkgClass\x10\x00\x1a\x00\n\x0c\n\x06TgType\x10\x00\x1a\x00\n\r\n\x07TgValue\x10\x00\x1a\x00'

print(escape_characters(blob))
```

Comment: Hello @Pablo . Thanks a lot it works removing the b attribute,
 but there is a one small issue i am getting the value of blob from  blob = tia.encode().
Is there any way so that the encode function doesn't return the b attribute?

Comment: don't use the encode function, and provider tia directly to escape_characters, or use the function decode.

Comment: @Kaustubhbhardwaj what are you going to do next with `blob`? That will determine the best answer.